# Wireless menu not showing up / wifi hardware disabled

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, network-manager, broadcom

So, this is the second time I'm attempting to fix this problem-

Unfortunately I can't exactly remember what fix worked, so here I am again.

There's a couple of aspects of the issue

The intermittent/occasional nature of the problem is especially perplexing.

It's about 50% of the time,when I turn on my computer, the wifi-menu in the upper right corner says 'wifi-hardware disabled'. It also does this when if I turn off the wifi- instead of giving me the option to 'select network'  it pops up with 'wifi-hardware disabled.'

However more recently, occasionally when I turn on my computer, it doesn't even give me the 'wifi hardware disabled' but any wifi-option at all in the upper right menu corner is completely missing.

The fix so far, which is clearly not a fix at all, is restarting/turning off and back on until I can actually connect... It seems as if the issue is worse on certain wifi-networks.....

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.3LTS, though, I have a dually- partitioned harddrive with Windows on the other partition, which honestly I've never touched- thought there might be programs I'd want to run- now it's just taking up space....
Intel® Core™ i3-3217U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 4

When I type in  lspci -nn | grep Network     I find

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
z@Mobius:~$

Comment: Lately, it's seemed like the problem is getting worse /

Comment: Either A) I turn on my computer and I have a wifi icon showing full connection, but every site i try to load returns "DNS not found" or B) I turn on my computer, wireless shows full connection, I open vivaldi and the first websites load, but by the time I fill out the comment box here and hit "add comment" We"re back to DNS not found.....      I"m wondering if this isnt partially a hardware issue.... my computer is an older, used when I got it Dell Lattitude 3330, and its a bit frankenstein- but more to the point, it lives in my backpack when i make the bikeride to town most days

Comment: Also, when I turn off/reboot my computer it comes up with error@ cfg_80211 something or other